# pfsense firewall filter rules behind nat?

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

i am new in pfsense
i have vmware which pfsense and windows xp are installed on them
pfsense in using ip **192.168.44.1** for LAN and **192.168.121.129** for wan (which is NAT)
 my win xp ip is **192.168.44.2** and its is connected to internet through pfsense
i want to filter addresses starting with **213.0.0.0**
but adding rules does not work
any solution?

Comment: What are you trying that does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

Filter addresses from where and to where? Blocking destination 213.0.0.0/8 via firewall rule will do what you want. 
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Firewall_Rule_Basics